# Angular 7 - PrimeNg ConfirmationDialog problem

Tags: typescript, angular7, primeng, angular-module

I have an `Angular` App that uses `PrimeNg` components. I have a problem with `ConfirmDialogModule`.

Here's my `html`:

```
  <p-table [columns]="tableCols" [value]="currentEstablishment.Sales" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true">
       <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns class="cervezapp-grid-header-column">
           <tr class="cervezapp-grid-header-row">
               <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngClass]="col.field == 'Date' ? 'col-header-date' : col.field == 'Detail' ? 'col-header-detail' : col.field =='Price' ? 'col-header-price' : col.field == 'SeeDet' ? 'col-header-seedet' : 'col-header-actions'">
                    <div [ngClass]="col.field == 'Date' ? 'col-header-date' : col.field == 'Detail' ? 'col-header-detail' : col.field =='Price' ? 'col-header-price' : col.field == 'SeeDet' ? 'col-header-seedet' : 'col-header-actions'">
                        {{col.header}}
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-sale let-columns="columns">
                <tr class="table-body-row">
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Fecha'">{{sale[col.field]}}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Detalle de venta'" class="table-body-col-small">{{sale[col.field]}}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Precio total'" class="table-body-col-small">$ {{sale[col.field]}}</span>
                        <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Ver Detalle'" class="table-body-col-small">
                            <img src="../../../assets/icons/Details.svg" class="delete-icon" (click)= "show()">
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="col.header == 'Acciones'" class="table-body-col-small">
                            <img src="../../../assets/icons/Delete.svg" class="delete-icon" (click)="openDeleteSaleModal(sale.Id)">
                            <img src="../../../assets/icons/Edit.svg" class="edit-icon">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           <p-confirmDialog ></p-confirmDialog>
      </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

And here's the `openDeleteSaleModal` method on my `.ts` file:

```
openDeleteSaleModal(Id: number){
    console.log("delete sale");
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Esta seguro que desea eliminar esta venta?',
      header: 'Eliminar Venta',
      icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
      accept: () => {
        console.log("Worked");
      },
      reject: () => {
        console.log("Test");
      }
    })
  }
```

Finally heres my `app.module` file

```
import {DynamicDialogModule} from 'primeng/dynamicdialog';


imports: [
    DynamicDialogModule
  ],
```

On the console log I just see that it's executed once, but the modal shows like this:

[image]

The screen turns black because there are like 10 instances of the modal opened. I have to press on cancel button like 10 times so the confirmdialog begins to close and the screen shows up again.

Any ideas of what could be wrong here?

Comment: Man you are creating your dialog instance at table body, so if there is an 500 rows on your table, the dialog opens up 500 times.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself, the problem was on the

```
<p-confirmDialog ></p-confirmDialog>
```

tag position, It should be outside the

```
<p-table>
</p-table>
```

I had a pagination of 10 rows and the modal opened 10 times, putting the

```
<p-confirmDialog ></p-confirmDialog>
```

outside the `table` solved the issue

Hope It helps someone in the future

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! I had exactly the same issue, I had a pagination of 10 rows and the confirm dialog opened 10 times. Couldn't figure out why it was happening until I read your answer :) Thanks a lot :)